# XCode always have misplaced views that need fixing when using size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

I am using `XCode 7` along with `Size Classes` (wCompact hRegular for all iPhones) and every time I open up `XCode` I have tons of Misplaced Views errors:

[image]

There are tons of them. So I have to go and fix the issues with each one.

Why does this continually happen? Is there a way I can fix this so it doesn't happen again?